# GTK+ tray/status menu not showing - arrows displayed instead

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, statusbar, tray

Trying to add a tray menu to a GTK+ (2.24) application on Windows 10, in C. Code is exactly as in this [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27142/Minimize-to-tray-with-GTK), except the icon. The result is as follows, menu is not visible and there are up and down arrows instead:

[image: Tray Menu Result]

In [this example](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d436780/c-cpp/bibliotheques/gtkp/gtkp-c-cpp/gtk-statusicon-menu-faire-menu-gtk/) (French forum, code works when an image is provided), only down arrow appears and it is possible sometimes (1 over 10) to actually display the menu entry by right-clicking long time on the arrow.

Question is: is this a GTK+ bug, as stated in several forums, or is there a way to create a menu from a tray icon using GTK+ without implementing a custom-drawn one?

Edit: replaced wrong GTK2 tag by GTK.

Comment: My guess is you have not renamed the icon to display to a locally available `.png` file on your computer (or used a path that Gtk understands, e.g. `/Users/you/Documents/....` or escaping with `"\\"` path separators). Otherwise, the first example works fine on both Linux and Win7 (I get the `View` and `Exit` popup menu on right-click on icon in the tray).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the comment. The icon is displayed (it's that one shown on the picture). It's the View and Exit that I cannot see on Win10, only those arrows. I'll also try on other environments and post an update.

Comment: Ah, OK, I'll boot Win10 and give it a try there.